# java class cant find variable in same project

Tags: java, swing, class, variables, symbols

**Hello! I am making a Super simple chat application in java with netbeans. I have one main class och one jframe class. in the jframe class i am trying to use this code:**

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String msg = jTextField1.getText();
    jTextArea1.setText(msg);
    String msgout = msg;
    dataout.writeUTF(msgout);
    dataout.flush();
    }
```

**But it says, cannot find symbol dataout. Here im using dataout in the main class:**

```
try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for clients to connect...");
            Socket s = ss.accept(); 
            DataOutputStream dataout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("Client connected!");

            }
            catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
```

**How do I solve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dataout is created inside the try/catch blocks its lifetime is only within these curly brackets. The best way would be to declare it as an instance variable and then access it like that.

Eg.

```
DataOutputStream dataout = null;

try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for clients to connect...");
            Socket s = ss.accept(); 
            dataout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("Client connected!");

            }
            catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
```

Comment: I did that now in the main class as you did, but the jFrameClass still cant find it, how do i write the code så that the jFrame can find it?

Comment: Is the JFrame class a separate class to the main class? You'd need to access the variable in a way that fits what you're doing, if so.

Comment: Yes, Its the same project but to seperate classes, first the main class which is handling the client who is connecting. And the other class is the jFrame class. The jFrame class doesn't seem to find any variables stored in the main class, that's the problem i thnk

Comment: You can't access any variables stored in another class unless you create an instance of that class. I'm not sure, but I think that the best thing you can do is to pass the dataout in through the constructor of the JFrame. Eg. CLASS jframeclass = new CLASS(dataout);